# JS AJAX typeahead result ordering / race condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, race-condition

I'm encountering an issue with AJAX typeahead / live-update as-you-type views which are returning results out of order. Does anyone have any experience with methods of dealing with this?

**The problem:**

1. Type in a query, such as "search term".
2. Even with some debouncing, it's likely to fire off a few AJAX calls as you type, say `"sea"`, and `"search term"`.
3. The search result set for `sea` is larger than the one for `search term`, and so its AJAX request actually completes after the newer query.
4. The resulting problem: You type in `search term`, but the correct results blip across the screen for a second only to be replaced by the results for `sea`.

Bare-bones jQuery pseudocode:

```
$('body').on('keyup', '#searchBox', function(){
    query = $("#searchBox").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/endpoint.php?query=' + query,
        success: function (response) {
            // Update view here
            $("#view").html(response.text);
        }
   });
});
```

Angular pseudocode:

```
// HTML
<input ng-keyup = "search()" ng-model="searchBox" placeholder = "Search">
{{results}}

// JS
$scope.search = function(){
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/endpoint.php?query=' + $scope.searchBox
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.results = response.data;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Top stop the race condition you can keep a reference to the last AJAX request you made and then `abort()` it when a new key is pressed. It would also be worthwhile putting a delay before making the request so that you don't send a request for every key pressed, but for when typing ends. Try this:

```
var previousRequest, previousTimer;

$('body').on('keyup', '#searchBox', function() {
    previousRequest && previousRequest.abort();
    clearTimeout(previousTimer);

    previousTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        previousRequest = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/endpoint.php',
            data: { 
                query: $("#searchBox").val() 
            },
            success: function (response) {
                // Update view here
                $("#view").html(response.text);
            }
        });
   }, 200);
});
```

200ms between keystrokes is plenty, but you can shorten if you want to increase the responsiveness of the requests.